# how can I purge a MassTransit queue?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, mq, masstransit

I'd like to delete all the messages from a queue in my integration test SetUp routine, how can I accomplish that? No luck with googling/intellisense-bruteforce.

If it matters -- I'm using RabbitMq as transport.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to "delete" from queues within MassTransit. For tests you can use temporary, random queue URIs via `rabbitmq://localhost/*?temporary=true`. Or you can just append `?temporary=true` to the end of your existing queue URIs to have MT clean stuff up afterward. Note: Current, as of 2.8, temporary exchanges aren't cleaned up. This should be fixed by the next release.

Comment: There's no way to "purge" the queues from within MassTransit. -- is it "by design"?

Comment: There is `SetPurgeOnStartup(true)` configuration option. Which might do what you want. Temporary queues are a better answer in RabbitMQ. However, if you feel like it needed, for whatever reason, and `SetPurgeOnStartup` doesn't cut it for you, submit an issue: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues

Comment: temporary queues appear to have been omitted in V2.9.5

Comment: They're in the latest v2 codebase, and have been for several releases.