# MassTransit: Event order

Tags: masstransit

Is there any way to guarantee that the events will be read by subscribers in the same order they were published? I am using the loopback queue at the moment, does that matter?

I have a console emulator that sends the console output lines as events. I may wait till the end of the command to return all the result as a single unit, but then interactive commands like "telnet" would not be possible.

The problem is, that sometimes, when the result set is long (like a "dir" command) some of the lines appears misplaced. The output appears to be published in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

While technically loopback should be in order as a by product of how it works, if you have multiple threads reading or writing then order is not guaranteed.

Also, loopback is really only for testing. It's not really a product ready interface.

You could use a Saga to hold the content of the message until you receive them in the right order. This would eliminate out of ordering issues. Also consider ensuring your consumer has a `ConcurrentConsumerLimit` of 1, so there's only ever one thread reading from the queue.

Comment: I see. Well that is the thing, that the queue is used for many "terminals", so it is ok if there are many. I cannot hold the messages, they need to be fired as soon they happen, so the terminal get feedback quick. I will take a look why messages in the same terminal have the wrong order, it may be something I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe each terminal should have it's own temp queue? For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179296/how-can-i-purge-a-masstransit-queue

Comment: Well, at the moment I am using only one terminal, so it wont make a difference :)